# Acsessing arrays in dictionary's

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary, char, int

Hello i have this piece of code

```
Dictionary<int[], char[]> items = new Dictionary<int[], char[]>();
```

I want to be able to get all the values of int[] and char[] i have tried

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int[], char[]> kvp in items)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Key = {0}, Value = {1}",
                    kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
            }
```

But this does not work it just outputs

```
Key = System32.Int32[], Value = System.Char[]
Key = System32.Int32[], Value = System.Char[]
Key = System32.Int32[], Value = System.Char[]
Key = System32.Int32[], Value = System.Char[]
Key = System32.Int32[], Value = System.Char[]
```

both arrays are the same length, in this case 5, so I'm just wondering how i access certain elements in the dictionary? normal methods don't work. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You have any array of int as your key, what else you expect as the output ? , You know that having an array of int as key in dictionary is useless ?

Comment: You have an `Int32[]` as a key and `Char[]` as a value. You read these values (which is Type names in such a case), not the values inside of them.

Comment: Yes i understand without a key i cant access the char array but i want to know if its possible?

Comment: How do i read the values inside them? is there a way?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you shouldn't be using a `Dictionary` to do this. Having an `int[]` array as your key is bad.

Comment: @Habib It's not useless, you'd just need to create a custom comparer that can compare the values of the array for it to have much value.

Comment: @RaymondTunstill Google could answer that question for you in a fraction of a second.

Comment: @Servy I have googled it, prove me wrong?

Comment: @RaymondTunstill [Sure](https://www.google.com/search?q=read+values+of+an+array+C%23&oq=read+values+of+an+array+C%23&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2.3880j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8)  4 out of the 5 top results all answer your question.

Comment: @Servy That isn't my question? my question is how to read from the arrays inside the dictionary.

Comment: @RaymondTunstill You've *already* pulled the arrays out of the dictionary, you have a single array, and you're trying to print it out, so no, that isn't what you're asking.  You're *just* asking how to read the values of an array.  Nothing more.

Comment: @Servy How have i? i can get the contents using string.Join but i want to access a certain element inside the array of the dictionary, for eaxmple items[1,1][1,1] would go to the first int array and pull the first character. and do the same for char[]

Comment: @RaymondTunstill That's not what your question is actually asking.  It's an entirely different problem.

Answer (score 2):

`Console.WriteLine` calls `ToString` on the arguments and what you are seeing is the behaviour of calling `ToString` method on a type that doesn't override `ToString`.Default implementation of `ToString` returns the type name.If you want to display your values in another format you need to do it manually.

For example, if you want to display array values in comma separated format you can use `string.Join`:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int[], char[]> kvp in items)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key = {0}, Value = {1}",
                string.Join("," kvp.Key), string.Join("," kvp.Value));
}
```

Comment: Thank you this works. How could i access the variables normally eg int j = items[1,1]?

Comment: @RaymondTunstill you need to pass an int array as a key.But even though you pass an array that has the same content you may not get the value you want. because arrays are compared based on reference by default. you need to provide a custom equality comparer to your dictionary so it can compare the keys based on the contents instead of references.

Comment: How would i go about this?

Comment: @RaymondTunstill there is an example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132072(v=vs.110).aspx) about how to use Dictionary with a custom comparer, and also an example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151(v=vs.110).aspx) about how to implement a custom equality comparer

Comment: @RaymondTunstill You can create a class like `class ArrayEqualsComparer<T> : EqualityComparer<T[]> where T : IComparable<T>
  {
    public override bool Equals(T[] x, T[] y)
    {
      return System.Collections.StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer.Equals(x, y);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode(T[] obj)
    {
      return System.Collections.StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer.GetHashCode(obj);
    }
  }`, then re-define your `items` into `items = new Dictionary<int[], char[]>(new ArrayEqualsComparer<int>());`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen What sytax would i use to access the values?

Comment: @RaymondTunstill The usual syntax, `char c = items[new[] { 2, 4, 6, }][3];`. What do you expect? Write your own class with a multi-parameter indexer, holding the `Dictionary<,>` as a field, if you want another syntax.